# how to download an audio instead of play it in crefsharp(winform)

Tags: cefsharp

If I open an audio link using cefsharp browser, for example:

[mp3](https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3)

It will play it in the browser.

I am wondering how to make cefsharp download it if the link is an audio.

One solution is to check the link and use System.Net.WebClient to save the link to a file, but if the link isn't end with mp3,wav,...etc
I still need to download it to check the file type.

Comment: Because you need to wait for the initial response to check the content type(mime type) it becomes a little difficult as CEF doesn't yet support modifying the response.  You can try checking the response mime type in http://cefsharp.github.io/api/96.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_Handler_ResourceRequestHandler_OnResourceResponse.htm and navigating back if audio after calling http://cefsharp.github.io/api/96.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_StartDownload.htm to download the file.

Comment: Alternatively you can use Or call http://cefsharp.github.io/api/96.0.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensionsEx_DownloadUrlAsync.htm  to download the file. See also https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-handling for basic usage example of implementing ResourceRequestHandler. I haven't tried your exact scenario, so let me know if this doesn't work.

Comment: @amaitland  Cool. It works like a charm!  Happy New Year:)

Comment: Great! If you have a chance to post your own answer that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution based on amaitlan's suggestion:

```
public class CustomResourceRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.ResourceRequestHandler
{
    protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        if (request.ResourceType == ResourceType.MainFrame && Uri.TryCreate(request.Url, uriKind: UriKind.Absolute, out Uri result))
        {
            //url is ended with mp3
            if (request.Url.EndsWith("mp3"))
            {
                //save the mp3
                using (WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    myWebClient.DownloadFile(request.Url, "test.mp3");
                }
                return CefReturnValue.Cancel;
            }
        }

        return CefReturnValue.Continue;

    }
}

public class CustomRequestHandler : CefSharp.Handler.RequestHandler
{
    protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
    {
        return new CustomResourceRequestHandler();
    }
}


//request handler
browser.RequestHandler = new CustomRequestHandler();
```